# Facebook post are not seen neither on the timeline nor in the Activity after posted successfully using iOS facebook sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using this code to share post to the facebook wall.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"http://www.apple.com/ipad-air-2/",@"link",nil];

 FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                                      parameters:params1];
 [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Done**: %@", result);

 }];
```

I got a success message after running the below code:

```
Id: { "id": "SOME_ID" }
```

But unfortunately this post are not seen neither on the timeline or activity log.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the right end point . try "me/feed" . that should fix your issue.

here is the link to the documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph